# ass values in allvalues and formData into a single array react js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to pass values in allvalues and formData into a single array and pass it throgh react axios

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
    allValues: {
        name: "",
        class: "",
        school: "",
       
      },
 files: {
        car: null,
        bus: null,
        scooter: null,
      },
};
```

```
 let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("antenatalChart", this.state.files.car);
axios.post("url",
        formData, //appand formdata and allValues

 {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`Success` + res.data);
      })
```

i am trying to pass values in allvalues and formData into a single array and pass it throgh react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs). This will help you understand how to handle multiple inputs in a form.